# LAMP: /var/www/html/index.html missing

Tags: lamp

I have a problem: I've just installed LAMP, and at some point I realized that `/var/www/html/index.html` is missing.

How can I get it back? If this file is the same for all machines, can anyone tell me where I can download it?

Answer (score 3):

`index.html` or `index.php` is the starting file of your web page.. (`example.com` usually is the same as `example.com/index.php` or `.html`) If you don't have none of these files create one and start inserting your lines of html (...)

Answer (score 0):

First find the package to reinstall...

```
lxd: net12-david-favor-zesty # dpkg -S $(which apache2)
apache2-bin: /usr/sbin/apache2
```

Now force reinstall the package.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2-bin
```

And this might be overkill. Likely this will also do the trick...

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apache2
```

Or you can just...

```
mkdir -p /var/www/html
echo "Default Page" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

To have a simple default page.